# Word to describe the state of belonging

Tags: single-word-requests

"An object A belongs to a group G by a degree R. R represents the degree of ...... of A to G."

What word can I use to replace the dots? Can I use "belongingness"? "Inclusion"?

Comment: Yes, "inclusion".  Why not?

Comment: I don't know why I feel it is awkward to use "inclusion" here. However I'm not a native English speaker, so I wanted to check. Is there another word that can be used in this context?

Comment: Include in your question the research you’ve done. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Inclusion

> 3 :  a relation between two classes that exists when all members of
> the first are also members of the second
> [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inclusion)

e.g.

> "An object A belongs to a group G by a degree R. R represents the
> degree of ***inclusion*** of A in G."

Yes inclusion works in the more specialised sense of the word above.

Another possibility is ***association***.

> a connection or relationship between things or people

e.g.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/association)

> "An object A belongs to a group G by a degree R. R represents the
> degree of ***association*** of A to G."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The suggestion of the word "association" is excellent. Another question, which preposition to use with "inclusion"? Is it "... inclusion of A to G." or "... inclusion of A in G."?

Comment: @eepgmja Good question, 'in' makes more sense. I've edited the response and your sample sentence to show this.